# Ansible "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ubuntu@ because target machine uses ec2-user

Tags: ssh, ansible

So I'm trying to use **roles** in Ansible and I'm not sure how to tell Ansible to use a specific user to **ssh**

So I have 2 files

**site.yml**

```
- hosts: _uat_web
- import_playbook: ../static-assignments/uat-webservers.yml
```

**uat-webservers.yml**

```
---
- hosts: _uat_web
  remote_user: ec2-user
  roles:
    - webservers
```

So if I run **ansible-playbook uat-webservers.yml** everything **works** as expected but the idea is for **site.yml** to call **uat-webservers.yml**

So when I run **ansible-playbook site.yml** I get this **issue**

```
UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).", "unreachable": true}
```

I know the issue is that the **target machine** is using Red Hat therefore I need user **ec2-user** for **ssh** to work.

I tried putting **remote_user: ec2-user** in **site.yml** did not work. FYI I'm executing the ansible playbooks on an Ubuntu machine thats why it defaults to ubuntu user

```
- hosts: _uat_web #uat-webservers
- remote_user: ec2-user
- import_playbook: ../static-assignments/uat-webservers.yml
```

In addition, I'm using dynamic inventory aws_ec2 I know with static inventory you can specify the user in the inventory. Would love a solution in the playbook itself such as **remote_user** that doesn't seem to work when using the import. Thank you

Comment: `I tried putting remote_user: ec2-user in site.yml did not work`. Where specifically did you try putting that line? Under `- hosts:`?

Comment: Yes betweem - hosts: _uat_web #uat-webservers and
- import_playbook: ../static-assignments/uat-webservers.yml

Answer (score 0):

In `site.yml`, this line by itself doesn't do anything (aside from gather facts). So it is redundant and can be removed.

```
- hosts: _uat_web
```

So if you remove that line, your import_playbook should work on it's own. ie.

```yaml
# site.yml
- import_playbook: ../static-assignments/uat-webservers.yml
```

If you really wanted that section because you wanted to run some stuff before importing the playbook, then do:

```yaml
# site.yml
- hosts: _uat_web
  remote_user: ec2-user  # Notice this line doesn't start with a "-" like it did in your example
  tasks:  # or roles:
    ...

- import_playbook: ../static-assignments/uat-webservers.yml
```

Edit:

Once the UNREACHABLE error is resolved, I think you may encounter another error where it cannot find the role. I'm not sure how your directory structure is setup, but when you use `import_playbook`, the imported playbook will look for the roles relative to itself.

Ie. your `../static-assignments/uat-webservers.yml` playbook calls the `webservers` role, then it will try to find it in `../static-assignments/roles/webservers` which may not exist in that path.

Some potential solutions is to look into the `roles_path` setting in `ansible.cfg`. Or potentially using a symlink to point to your main roles directory.

Comment: I'm following the example of somebody else and was wondering about the redundancy of hosts thanks for confirming. Still doesn't fix my issue though

Comment: Can you show the updated code that still doesn't work. You removed the first `- hosts` and only have the import_playbook in site.yml and that still doesn't work?

Comment: @user312042 See the edit in my answer. Is that what you're experiencing now?